# doInBackground process in AsyncTask Android doesn't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the code which execute AsyncTask to call API, but there is nothing going on when I tried to debug it. The pointer exit from onPreExecute and not get in to doInBackground. I don't know why.

```
class MasterBrand extends AsyncTask<String, String, AsyncTaskResult<ResponBrand>> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<ResponBrand> s) {
        Log.e("", "CollectionResult.onPostExecute");
        
        try{
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();    
        Log.e("", "CmoProductivity.onPreExecute");
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("harap tunggu sebentar...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult<ResponBrand> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ResponBrand cmoPoDp = new ResponBrand();
        try
        {
            Type listTypeTaskHeader = new TypeToken<ResponBrand>() {}.getType();
            JSONHttpClient jsonHttpClient = new JSONHttpClient();
            List<NameValuePair> argsTaskHeader = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Log.e("", "Get Task Header Data");
            cmoPoDp = jsonHttpClient.Get(StringAPIurl, argsTaskHeader, ResponBrand.class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            Log.e("", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new AsyncTaskResult<ResponBrand>(cmoPoDp);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you call it ? add the calling code .. Also see if you get any exception add the error logs too .Also remove `dialog.isShowing()` code from `doInBackground`.

Comment: this how i called it new MasterBrand.execute(),
but when I debug the pointer exit from onPreExecute wich is , it shoud be go to doinBackground.
but in this case it exits from onPreExecute after showdialog whithout dismiss it

Comment: It Should be new MasterBrand(). execute (""). Are you calling it like this ??

Comment: It would help if you could add the calling part too. And also check if the Log added in  doInBacakground gets logged or not.